# Validity of UK passport required to visit Italy

Tags: passports, italy, uk-citizens

I am planning a trip to Italy in January of 2012. I am just wondering if I will be allowed to enter the country as my UK passport has less than 6 months remaining until it is due to be renewed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just leave before it expires.

The [Italian embassy in London](http://www.amblondra.esteri.it/Templates/PaginaInterna.aspx?NRMODE=Published&NRNODEGUID=%7BE9703239-71BD-4C80-90D9-1BCC6B4CA81B%7D&NRORIGINALURL=/Ambasciata_Londra/Menu/In_linea_con_utente/Domande_frequenti/&NRCACHEHINT=NoModifyGuest#1) says this:

> 1.2 UK Passport validity for travelling to Italy Foreigners may travel to Italy provided their UK passport is valid when they exit Italy (no
>   minimum validity required). This applies to all EU passport-holders.
>   If you have a non EU passport, please consult the website of the
>   Italian Foreign Ministry to verify whether you need a visa to enter
>   Italy

Comment: Would have helped if you left out the unnecessary detail and focused on the last paragraph, which is relevant.

Comment: for those of you playing along at home, thats rewrite number 3!

Answer (score 1):

From the [Lonely Planet visa site](http://lonelyplanet.visaheadquarters.co.uk/visa_info.php?id=100&ctz=213&loc=213) for UK citizens visiting Italy:

> All travelers will need a passport valid for at least 90 days
>   following your departure date from Italy. However, we strongly
>   recommend traveling with 6 months validity on your passport at all
>   times. Citizens of United Kingdom can refer to www.ips.gov.uk for
>   forms and instructions for new passport applications and British
>   passport renewals.

Comment: So assuming the Italian embassy is right (see Stuart's answer), Lonely Planet got it wrong (not the first time).